# Can you guys help with blocking the token until a certain time?

Tags: solidity

Here code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";

contract Testoken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Pausable, Ownable, ERC20Permit {
    constructor()
        ERC20("Testoken", "TOKEN")
        ERC20Permit("Test token")
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, 900000 * (10**6) * (10 ** uint256(18)));
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }
    uint256 time = 3 weeks;
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount){
        if(public onlyOwner != public onlyOwner){
            require(block.timestamp > time);
        }
      //code
    }

    function transferFrom(address to, uint256 amount){
        if(!public onlyOwner){
            require(block.timestamp > time);
        }
      // rest of the code
    }
}
```

I need to block the sale of the token after it goes on the exchange other than the founder. How do I implement this? Wrote an outline but it doesn't work.
If it works, I want to completely block the sale of the token on the exchange.

Comment: No, we can't help you scam people, sorry. And i'm voting to close this question, of course

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do but take a look at OpenZeppelin `TokenTimelock` contract https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/TokenTimelock.sol.

Comment: Your transfer from function looks fishy